# How does window tumbling works in ksql? As query returning same result with or without using window tumbling in ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am using ksql stream and calculating events coming every 5 minutes. Here is my query -

```
select count(*), created_on_date from TABLE_NAME window tumbling (size 5 minutes) group by created_on_date;
```

Providing results -

```
2 | 2018-11-13 09:54:50
3 | 2018-11-13 09:54:49
3 | 2018-11-13 09:54:52
3 | 2018-11-13 09:54:51
3 | 2018-11-13 09:54:50
```

query without window tumbling -

```
select count(*), created_on_date from OP_UPDATE_ONLY group by created_on_date;
```

Result -

```
1 | 2018-11-13 09:55:08
2 | 2018-11-13 09:55:09
1 | 2018-11-13 09:55:10
3 | 2018-11-13 09:55:09
4 | 2018-11-13 09:55:12
```

Both queries returning same results, so how does window tumbling make difference?

Answer (score 2):

The tumbling window is a rolling aggregation and counts the number of events based on a key within a given window of time. The window of time is based on the timestamp of your stream, inherited from your Kafka message by default but overrideable by `WITH (TIMESTAMP='my_column')`. So you could pass `created_on_date` as the timestamp column and then aggregate by the values there.

The second one is over the entire stream of messages. Since you happen to have a timestamp in your message itself, grouping by that gives the illusion of a time-based aggregation. However, if you wanted to find out how many events, for example, within an hour - this would be no use (you can only do a count at the grain of `created_on_date`).

So the first example, with a window, is usually the correct way to do it because you usually want to answer a business question about an aggregation *within a given time period*, **not** over the course of an arbitrary stream of data.